# Syntax error: “(” unexpected when execute a cross compiled PJSIP binary in ARM

Tags: arm, cross-compilation

I am working on PJSIP on the Cortex A8 ARM processor. I built the executable PJSIP binary using Code Sourcery Cross compiler by following command

```
./configure --host=arm-elf-linux.
```

Resulting binary doesn't got executed in ARM processor throwing

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected.
```

My ARM processor works on linux kernel 2.6.37. 
Can anyone point me why am getting above error and will the PJSIP_2.1.0 supports above linux kernel and if it won't support is their any PJSIP version support for linux 2.6.37?

Comment: Did you really have the `.` on the end of the `configure` call? That looks wrong.

Comment: Does that error come from the `configure` script itself, or from the binary you got after `configure` was run and you compiled the program with `make` or such?

Comment: Compare the output of `file yourexecutable` with `file /bin/sh` on your arm system.

Comment: That's because your system doesn't recognize that executable as a binary, and tries to run it as a script via `/bin/sh` (that's standard behavior from `execvp` or `execlp` when the `execve` failed with `ENOEXEC`). It's probably because you didn't cross-compile it as you believe, but compiled it for the platform you did the build on. The `--host=arm-elf-linux-` arg to `configure` needs a `-`, not a `.` at the end, as PhilipKendall already [remarked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499641/syntax-error-unexpected-when-execute-a-cross-compiled-pjsip-binary-in-arm#comment920035_499641)

Comment: What does `file(1)` says about that binary? What does `uname -a` says about the system you try to run it on?

Comment: No, I don't put . at end of configure command. I just put that to indicate end of sentence. I will give the output of file command after trying that.

Comment: as @mosvy pointed, binary was built for linux host only. the issue is CC variable is not set properly. After proper initialization CC variable, now it started running in ARM. Now we were running into different issue which I had posted separately in this thread.https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502012/beginners-guide-multiple-calls-in-pjsip

Comment: @SyedAhmed how to set CC variable?